# De que forma criar um vetor de Registro no PLSQL

Tags: java, oracle, pl-sql

Tenho um registro de

```
    TYPE trec IS RECORD ( 
        cd_multi_empresa NUMBER(8,2),
        tp_atendimento   CHAR(2)
      );

vcAtendimento trec;
```

Preciso de um vetor de registro, usei esta e comando:

```
TYPE TcAtendimento IS VARRAY(10) OF vcAtendimento;
```

> No fim recebo uma mensagem de erro: Relatório de erros - ORA-06550:
>   linha 8, coluna 39: PLS-00488: 'VCATENDIMENTO' must be a type
>   ORA-06550: linha 8, coluna 1: PL/SQL: Item ignored ORA-06550: linha
>   13, coluna 41: PLS-00321: expression 'TcAtendimento ' is
>   inappropriate as the left hand side of an assignment statement
>   ORA-06550: linha 13, coluna 5: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Comment: TYPE TcAtendimento IS VARRAY(10) OF trec ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de ler a documentação do oracle PLSQL:

```
TYPE TcAtendimento IS VARRAY(10) OF trec;
```